# Posting works on localhost but not on live server

Tags: php, mysqli

Code works on localhost but not live server. Simply posting form and I don't know what to do. Connectin is OK. I tried and it works fine. I also checked header and path is OK. Problem might be about values. Any helps would be great. Thanks..

Here's my code

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","servet","getwell","chance");
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");


// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");

if(isset($_POST['send'])) { 
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

    $q ="insert into service(name,email,ip) values ('$name','$email','$ip')"; 

    if (mysqli_query($conn,$q))                                                                                   
    {
        header('Location: product.php');
        exit(header("Location: product.phpr"));
    }   
    else {
        echo "<h2 style='text-align:center; padding:1px; margin-top:-3%;'>Try later</h2>"; 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);` and add error checking to the mysql

Comment: can you add these lines to the top of your code and post here the errors?

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Are you using a localhost db on your live server?

Comment: this is what ı got Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in /home2/servet/public_html/product_detail/add.php on line 26

Comment: using live server thanks for such a quick answer

Comment: what is on line 26 of `/home2/servet/public_html/product_detail/add.php `? im asking in case there is some sort of other file being referenced here not shown in code.

Comment: product_detail is a file where add.php is into. servet is my domain name and add.php is where the code I asked.

Comment: Change `$q ="ins...` to `$q ='insert into service(name,email,ip) values ("{$name}","{$email}","{$ip}")'; `, then try again. If it not work, try printing the `$p` variable right after the command and let us know.

Comment: vietanhyt thanks for your help but it's not working